# MySQL database design for a data set with variable amount of columns

Tags: mysql

What I have is about 130GB of time varying state data of several thousand financial instruments' orderbooks.

The csv files I have contain a row per each change in the orderbook state (due to an executed trade, inserted order etc.). The state is described as: a few fields of general orderbook information (e.g. isin code of the instrument), a few fields of information about the state change (such as orderType, time) and finally the buy and sell levels of the current state. There are up to 20 levels (Buy level 1 representing the best buy price, sell level one representing the best sell price and so on.) of both sell and buy orders, and each of them consist of 3 fields (price, aggregated volume and order amount). Finally there is additional 3 field of aggregated data of the levels beyond 20 for both buy and sell side. This amounts to total maximum of 21*2*3 = 126 fields of the levels data per state.

The problem is that since there rarely exists anywhere near 20 levels it doesn't seem to make sense to reserve fields for each of them. E.g. I'd have a rows where there are 3 buy levels and the rest of the fields are empty. On the other hand the same orderbook can have 7 buy levels after a few moments.

I will definitely normalize the general orderbook info into it's own table, but I don't know how to handle the levels efficiently.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look to other non relational database systems as CouchDB or MongoDB. Both of them are less rigid than MySQL because you can define different fields in every record of the "tables".

Comment: Seems like you could have the 'levels' in a separate table then join and sort to get the first, second, so on. If you needed them all displayed in one row for a select you would use a series of ifnull() clauses.

Comment: @mvillaress: This has crossed my mind, but due to my existing systems, data (in MySQL db) and skills/knowledge it would be far more convenient to do this in MySQL if I can only make it work somehow.

Comment: @ethrbunny: I'm not sure I understand what you are suggesting. The only way I see separate tables for levels helping the problem of unnecessary fields is if there is one table / row in source data, since the amount of fields required varies over orderbooks, and over time for a single orderbook.

Answer (score 0):

I have had to deal with exactly this structure of data, at one point in time.  One important question is how the data will be used.  If you are only looking for the best bid and ask price at any given time, then the levels do not make much of difference.  If you are analyzing market depth, then the levels can be important.

For the volume of data you are using, other considerations such as indexing and partitioning may be more important.  If the data you need for a particular query fits into memory, then it doesn't matter how large the overall table is.

My advice is to keep the different levels in the same record.  Then, you can use page compression (depending on your storage engine) to eliminate most of the space reserved for the empty values.  SQL Server does this automatically, so it was a no-brainer to put the levels in a single record.

A compromise solution, if page compression does not work, is to store a fixed number of levels.  Five levels would typically be populated, so you wouldn't have the problem of wasted space on empty fields.  And, that number of levels may be sufficient for almost all usage.

Comment: The data will be used for research purposes. At first we are mainly interested in the best bid/ask, but market depth analysis will follow in time, so I want to do this properly from the beginning. Queries will likely be mostly about getting a set of levels for a certain time window and for different uses indexing can be done when needed. I can't afford to limit the maximum amount of levels, but what you wrote about page compression is good news to me. Now it just comes down to choosing the engine that does this best.